# Counting lines in python without using a textfile

Tags: python, json, list, counting

I finally filtered my script to just output what I want.
And it works... half!

With the help of some of the amazing people here I managed to create a script that auto accepts friend requests on snapchat, though I want to have a counter in it that sees how many confirmed friends someone has.

That's not the biggest problem though, and I already fixed it.
By using the following code;

```
for friend in friends:
    if friend['type'] == 0:
        names = friend[u'name']
        print names
```

it prints the names nicely, my results for example are:

```
test.account2
test.account3
test.account4
etc...
```

This is awesome, so far.

Now I want to count, how many friends that actually are and print that number.

So in this case, the number would be 3 (obviously, not taking the "etc" in mind)

Though, I have tried, len, count, str.count and a lot of other things, but it just doesn't seem to work.
First of all, it prints it out 3 times, which I get, because of it's indent.
But moving the indent back, makes it "forget" `names`

And so far the only thing I manged to do is print out the letter count for all 3 names in the following manner:

```
13
13
13
```

Am I overlooking something here, or just being stupid?

Help is appreciated!

Comment: What did you mean "but it just doesn't seem to work"? Built-in function len() must return valid array length. What's the type of friends variable?

Comment: can you paste your full code?. Do you know about namespaces? Getting `names` out from `if` make it loose value. So `print names` should give an error because `names` is not defined.

Comment: Really, the variable `names` should be called `name` instead.  That might help you think about what you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `names` variable is not an array. It just stores the name of the current friend item as `friends` is looped over. Therefore you also 3 times get the length of 13, since it's just the character count of that particular name string as it's encountered.

To get an array of names you can do this:

```
names = []
for friend in friends:
    if friend['type'] == 0:
        names.append(friend[u'name'])
```

Or simpler:

```
names = [friend[u'name'] for friend in friends if friend['type'] == 0]
```

Then `len(names)` will provide the name count.

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing `13` because that is the length of each name `test.account2`, etc. This is because you called `len` on `names` like this `len(names)` which is not what you want.

Initialize a list above your for-loop: `name_list = []` and append the names to this list:

```
name_list = []
for friend in friends:
    if friend['type'] == 0:
        names = friend[u'name']
        print names
        name_list.append(names)

print 'Added %d names' % (len(name_list))
```

The final `print` should now dump `3` per your example.

Comment: Thanks for your input, definitely helped me :)